# In a Jupyter notebook, is it possible to configure it to automatically display a (decorated) function where it's defined?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I have a decorate that adds a `_repr_html_` method to an object, and I use it on a function `foo`:

```py
def add_repr_html(f):
    f._repr_html_ = lambda: f"This is {f.__name__}!"
    return f

@add_repr_html
def foo():
    ...
```

If that is the content of the code cell in Jupyter, it won't display anything. However, if I add `foo` on a separate line afterward, it will display "This is foo!".

Is there a way to configure Jupyter so that putting `foo` on a separate line isn't necessary for it to be displayed? I would like for to automatically call the `_repr_html_` method without needing the extra line.

(Note that this is a toy example. In my actual use case, the decorator instantiates a class with a `_repr_html_` method.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using IPython input transformations as discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-there-an-option-to-enable-cellmagic-on-every-cell/17852/4?u=fomightez).
For my toy implementation below am mostly relying on the code example just below that post and building in adding to the end upon catching a certain condition.

### Toy implementation to handle your toy example

Put this is at the top of you notebook and run it first:

```py
def monitor4decorator_and_do_the_thing(lines):
    new_lines = [] 
    if '@add_repr_html\n' in lines:
        new_lines.append("foo \n")

    return lines + new_lines

ip = get_ipython()
ip.input_transformers_cleanup.append(monitor4decorator_and_do_the_thing)
```

Now run this working variation on your toy example code, and it should do what you asked and other cells should run as normal.

```py
def add_repr_html(f):
    f._repr_html_ = lambda: f"This is {f.__name__}!"
    return f

@add_repr_html
def foo():
    pass
```

Obviously, you'd abstract the code more to detect a decorated function in general and act accordingly to invoke the function.

Note:
For my toy implementation above, I saw that use of `input_transformers_post` in place of `input_transformers_cleanup` worked, too. I'm not quite sure yet when you'd want one or the other based on [the input transformation docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/inputtransforms.html#string-based-transformations). I bring it up because your situation isn't as simple as your toy example and so it may be handy?

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I think that doing the text search and modification will work for 90% of use cases, but isn't as robust as I like -- like what if someone has a function that creates, decorates, and returns `foo`, and then invokes that function? I think what I want is some way to add a hook that inspects the object as the code is run, and decides whether to call `display()` on it.