# Cannot mix code and math in display of output cells in Jupyter

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter

I'm trying to mix math and code strings in an output cell of a Jupyter notebook :

````
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
text = """
Formula is $\\lambda = \\rho \\cdot C_p$

It corresponds to the python code:

> ```python
> lambda = rho * Cp
> ```
"""
display(Markdown(text))
````

However, in the output cell, only the python string is correctly displayed: the inline math formula remains as it is, enclosed with '$'. Removing the python code snippet allows to correctly display the math formula, meaning there's a kind of inconsistency between both modes. Why and how to solve this?

Comment: I think you need to specify where you are trying to run this? As in which specific version and which specific Jupyter tech. You **current** code works just fine in JupyterLab version 3.4.8 and 4.0.6. **As well as  Jupyter Notebook`Version: 7.0.4` and `7.1.0a2` I think I am seeing what you describe in Jupyter NbClassic 0.5.5. (And even in JupyterLab Version 4.1.0b0.) In this case, removing the three backticks in front of  `python` and after the last caret works to fix it, in line with what you say. Of course, then you lose the code highlighting. ...

Comment: <continued>The issue is some old versions of the classic style interface had a regression in sorting out combined/nested use of triple quoted text and backticks. I thought that this since been fixed as evidenced by your example works in most newer versions of JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook interface. But now I'm seeing it not work again in JupyterLab Version 4.1.0b0 that just came out December 28, of course that is marked **beta**. I'm not quite sure where to post about this apparent newer regression in JupyterLab right now? ...

Comment: <continued> I don't think it is [this issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/15411), but I cannot be sure because I was copying your supplied text and didn't write it out myself. My thinking is this apparent regression needs a new issue if you care to elevate it to that. (We'd have to rule out line endings though, I think?!?!) Anyway, the straightforward solution is to make it less complicated and remove the nesting. Because I cannot easily post code here, I'm going to propose as an answer a work around that works everywhere by taking out the nested / combined issue.

Comment: Used version is Jupyter notebook 7.0.6

Comment: Hmm...I don't know where to report it or look into it further given that version number?  That falls in between JupyterLab 7.0.4 and 7.1.0a2 which would suggest the underlying issue snuck back in then got fixed by Jupyter Notebook Version 7.1.0a2 and came back again over in JupyterLab. (Which seems overly convoluted to be true?) The fact that it works in Jupyter Notebook Version 7.1.0a2 suggest if you eventually update it wouldn't be an issue, I think. Anyway, the nesting seems to be the issue and there is a workaround you can opt in to that makes it work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is sorting out the triple backtick inside a triple-quoted multiline string. It is quite complex and my limited investigation seems to regress often probably trying to fix something else.
I'm seeing your code work as is in various versions of Jupyter.
**Here is where it works**:

- JupyterLab version 3.4.8 and 4.0.6. **As well as  Jupyter Notebook`Version: 7.0.4` and
- JupyterLab version 4.0.6
- Jupyter Notebook Version 7.0.4
- Jupyter Notebook Version 7.1.0a2

Here is where I see the first formula **not display as MathJax**:

- Jupyter NbClassic 0.5.5. (which I think is closely related to Jupyter Notebook 6.4.1 because the system had that, too)
- JupyterLab Version 4.1.0b0

Proposed solution to remove the complexity of the nested triple-quoted/ticked markdown by making them two strings as a workaround that will work anywhere. Your example with that implemented:

````py
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
texta = """
Formula is $\\lambda = \\rho \\cdot C_p$
"""

textb = """
It corresponds to the python code:

> ```python
> lambda = rho * Cp
> ```
"""
display(Markdown(texta))
display(Markdown(textb))
````

Comment: Many thanks, Wayne, for poking around this topic. This workaround works actually. However, my initial purpose was to allow the notebook user to display the documentation of a python class, which string was built by mixing both types (inline math formula and triple ticked python code), somthing like "display(Markdown(myclass.__doc__))". Therefore I needed only one "text" to be displayed as Markdown. I'll see however if an upgrade of version will solve the issue.

Comment: I was worried it was something like that. I think there is a way you could make some boilerplate code that the user runs at the start of the notebook that would do some  behind the scenes handling to insure it breaks it into to two text strings `display(Markdown(XXXXX.__doc__))`. Of course, it would be very much opaque to a novice user, and they'd have to know to always run that to use that. And it seems like a lot of effort to go through for an intermittent  problem (meaning comes and goes with various Jupyter versions, it seems) that you can just explain or remove the backticks.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's an interesting idea... I'll see if I can provide a function for this, available to the user.

Comment: What I was thinking of was something along the lines of what I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77282760/8508004). In that case the code in a cell was monitored for a match to `@add_repr_html\n` and then run the code as if `foo` was added to the last line while the user doesn't see it as such. That way you provide some code to run early on that would look for something like `display(Markdown(XXXXX.__doc__))` & fix it to run the equivalent of my suggestion sort of approach, while hopefully allowing most normal use of generic `display(Markdown(<all_other_strings>))` code.

Comment: Yep. This should work. I was not aware of these input transformations for IPython!